# expand ADT on mac error 2

Tags: android, macos, cordova, sdk

Im using mac OS X10.8.2 and Cordova 2.2.0, and I'm trying to install Android SDK as mentioned in the [documentation of phonegap](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.2.0/guide_getting-started_android_index.md.html#Getting%20Started%20with%20Android), after i download the ADT zip file, an error message appear :

```
     Unable to expand "adt-bundle-mac-x86_64.zip" into "adt-bundle-mac-x86_64".
     (Error 2- no such file or directory.)
```

I've google the error several times, and I download the file several times also. 
Most of reviews said that the file maybe corrupted, do you know where to find another source to download the Android SDK or simply how to fix the file.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same issue. It seems like while it is downloading, the file says it is 373 MB and once it is done, it is 98.6 MB. Not sure how that works.

But I went and downloaded Eclipse, added https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/ to the available software sites and it pulled in the SDK. So I guess that is the solution for now.